# How to pass a character value to a function in order to execute a singleton select within?

Tags: postgresql

My question is rather simplistic in nature; I am trying to write a short but sweet function in postgresql where I can pass it a schema name and it will return me a list of tables that are associated with that schema.

For example, I want to place this sql within a function, pass it the schemaname and then execute it within...

```
SELECT SCHEMANAME, TABLENAME

FROM PG_TABLES

WHERE SCHEMANAME = variable being passed in the function ()
```

Would appreciate the most simplistic answer you may have.

Comment: Make sure to include the version of PostgreSQL you are using in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tables(ip_schemaname name) RETURNS TABLE(schemaname NAME, tablename name)
AS 
$$ 
    SELECT schemaname, tablename 
    FROM pg_tables 
    WHERE schemaname = ip_schemaname;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;


SELECT * FROM get_tables('public');
```